# Cant find in stack work answer on: How to know when Firebase retrieved data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

please explain where (method or maybe exists observe with competition method) I need retrieve data from Firebase. What is best practices?

```
    var ref:FIRDatabaseReference!

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    //filling ShopList by favorite
    ref.child("goods").observeSingleEvent(of:.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            print("my app: 1. Start ObserveSingle")

            for snap in snapshots {

                let g = Good()
                g.barcode = String(describing: snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "barcode").value!)
                g.name = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value! as! String
                g.price = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "minprice").value! as! Double
                g.favorite = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "favorite").value! as! Bool

                if g.favorite {//избранные товары
                    DataService.dataService.dbShopList.append(g)
                }
            }

            print("my app: 2. Observe finished \(DataService.dataService.dbShopList.count)")
        }

    })

    print("my app: 3. observe finished \(DataService.dataService.dbShopList.count)")
```

How to understand when and where finished step 2

Debug below

```
    my app: 3. observe finished 0
    my app: 1. Start ObserveSingle
    my app: 2. Observe finished 3
```

Comment: What are you trying to ask? Your prints show you when things happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase data is only valid within the closure following the observe. So when you call

```
ref.child("goods").observeSingleEvent(of:.value, with: { 
     //this is the closure where the data is returned and valid
})
```

Here's the getcha....

```
print("my app: 3.
```

will be called BEFORE

```
print("my app: 2.
```

because code executes faster than the internet!

There is a delay in Firebase returning data which will cause the closure to fire *after* the print statement that's outside the closure.

Work with Firebase data INSIDE the closure as that's the only time it's valid. Trying to access that data before it's ready will result in nil data as the variables will not be populated until the closure is called.

It takes time to get used to setting up sequences of events based on Firebase data being returned.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
myDataSource = []

Query Firebase for data {
  populate the data source with Firebase data
  reload the tableView
}

don't access the data source here as it won't be ready
```

We can put that into practice using a snippet of code from your question

```
var ref:FIRDatabaseReference!
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

ref.child("goods").observeSingleEvent(of:.value, with: {(snapshot) in

     print("data from the snapshot is ready to be used")

     for child in snapshot.children {
         var g = Good()
         let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
         let dict = snap.value! as! [String:String]
         g.barcode = dict["barcode"]!
         DataService.dataService.dbShopList.append(g)
     }

     print("All the firebase data was read in, show it in the tableView")
     self.tableView.reloadData()

 })

 print("This will execute before the closure completes so")
 print("  don't do anything with the Firebase data here")
```

Comment: thank you for theory, could you give a practice example?

Comment: @LeonifNif I am not sure if can give an example as your code is fine - it's understanding the flow of data that's the issue. Firebase is asynchronous in nature so you can't work with snapshot data until Firebase has returned that data - and the data is only valid inside the observe closure. I added some example code (untested as I am on my iPad) that should step you through the flow.